# "focus on" or "concentrate on"

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I am wondering if "focus" and "concentrate" can be used interchangeably?

Such as:

- [..] designed solution will **focus on** using modern hardware [..]
- [..] designed solution will **concentrate on** using modern hardware [..]

Comment: Yes, they can both be used here!! I think that your questions are more for ELL rather than ELU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "focus" and "concentrate" are almost always used interchangeably. There are situations in which one sounds better than another (e.g. "focus one's effort" versus "contentrate one's effort") but I think in all situations they are functionally equivalent.